# enumerate matches in string

Tags: regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I'm overriding my string class do simplify the execution of regular expressions. It worked fine till I upgraded to Xcode 7 beta and swift 2.0.

```
regex.enumerateMatchesInString(str, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: all) {
        (result : NSTextCheckingResult!, _, _) in

// do stuff
}
```

I keep getting the error  "Cannot invoke 'enumerateMatchesInString' with an argument list of type '(String, options: NSMatchingOptions, range: _NSRange, (NSTextCheckingResult!, _, _) -> _)'"

I can get it to work without adding the closure/block in, but that defeats the purpose of using enumerate matching in string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could work if you change `NSTextCheckingResult!` to `NSTextCheckingResult?` because this is the actual declaration.

Comment: Awesome. The ? ! throw me off sometimes. Good catch.